# Guy with $7$ friends

Tags: combinatorics

Some guy has $7$ friends$(A,B,...,G)$. He's making dinner for $3$ of them every day for one week. For how many ways can he invite $3$ of them with condition that no couple won't be more then once on dinner. (When we took $A,B,C$ we cannot take $A$ with $B$ or $C$ and $B$ with $C$). My idea: We have $7$ subset with $3$ elements. So $7!$,but subset $\{A,B,C\}=\{B,A,C\}$ etc. So we have to divide by $3!$, but I don't think that's correct thinking. Should I divide also by couples? ($2!^3$) Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Either I am missing something or the book answer is wrong. I take it that when you write "no couple **won't** be more than once on dinner", you actually mean "no couple **will** ....." as has been amply clarified in your examples.

Now there can only be $\dbinom72 = 21$ distinct couples, and each day $3$ such couples get eliminated, e.g. if $ABC$ are invited, $AB, BC$ and $AC$ can't be invited again.

Thus there are only $7$ trios to be invited, and if the order in which they are invited is to be considered, there are $7!$ ways of inviting them.

**Note**

There is no question of dividing by $3!$, because we considered *combos* of $3$, and for the life of me, I can't understand multiplication by $2$  and division by $2^2$]

Answer (score 0):

We can chose 3 men from 7 in <sup>$7$</sup>$C$<sub>$3$</sub> many ways. That is $35$. Now, a couple repeats $5$ times. So, the we can chose three men with the criteria in $35/5=7$ many ways. Now, there are $7$ parties in total. So, we can permute the groups across days. That gives a total of $7!$ many ways.

Comment: I checked in book and the awnser is $\frac{7!*2}{2!^2*3!}$

Comment: Does the ordering matter? I mean on which day a trio is invited...

Comment: Yes. There is a difference between Monday and Tuesday

Comment: true blue anil's answer coincides with mine.

Comment: I think his (or her) awnser is correct. I'll ask the authors of book, how did they find this numbers. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hmm... He made a different approach... But, in the end, we both agree to the same answer...